# Two dimensional lookup?

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup, spreadsheet, lookup, flatten

I have a sheet called Shipping that contains the standard shipping costs.
In the columns, I have product.
In the rows, I have destination countries.
So each cell tells me the price to send product to country for the (product, country) pair.

I have another sheet that captures live information on orders.
Column C has product name, and column G has country name.
In column R, I have to provide the shipping cost, based on a lookup of the Shipping sheet.

I am at a loss here, as I am familiar with VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP, but they are uni-dimensional lookups...the number of products/countries is large and dynamic, so I don't want to simply create a separate table to create another lookup for the column/row number to input as index in my original lookup...unless I have to.

Would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried INDEX MATCH? It combines the functionality of VLOOKUP and HLOOKUP.
Good resource here:
https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2019/12/17/index-match-match-two-dimensional-lookup-excel/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(F2:F&"×"&G2:G, SPLIT(FLATTEN(
 IF(B2:D="",,A2:A&"×"&B1:D1&"♦"&B2:D)), "♦"), 2, 0)))
```

[image]