# Extracting data from table and multiple sheets using conditional logic

Tags: google-sheets, extract

I am trying to create a custom template for writing a condensed description in google sheets. First, I want the information from both the "title" and "notes" column under "input" sheet to be denoted as the first and second statement respectively.

Then, given the material and condition information, I want to extract and add the information from the cross-reference table under "condition*_*chart*"

---

**INPUT SHEET**

[image: input sheet]

---

**CONDITION CHART**

[image: condition chart]

---

This is what I have so far.

```
function getDescription(title, notes, material, condition) {
  let description = """";
  if (title) {
    description += title + "". "";
  }
  if (notes) {
    description += notes + "". "";
  }
  if (material && condition) {
    if (material === ""CD"" && condition === ""M"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(2, 2).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""CD"" && condition === ""NM or M-"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(2, 3).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""CD"" && condition === ""VG+/EX"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(2, 4).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""CD"" && condition === ""VG"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(2, 5).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""CD"" && condition === ""G/G+"" || ""G+"" || ""G"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(2, 6).getValue(); 
    } else if (material === ""CD"" && condition === ""P"" || ""F"" || ""F/P"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(2, 7).getValue(); 
    } else if (material === ""Cassette"" && condition === ""M"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(3, 2).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Cassette"" && condition === ""NM or M-"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(3, 3).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Cassette"" && condition === ""VG+/EX"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(3, 4).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Cassette"" && condition === ""VG"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(3, 5).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Cassette"" && condition === ""G/G+"" || ""G+"" || ""G"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(3, 6).getValue(); 
    } else if (material === ""Cassette"" && condition === ""P"" || ""F"" || ""F/P"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(3, 7).getValue(); 
    } else if (material === ""Vinyl"" && condition === ""M"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(4, 2).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Vinyl"" && condition === ""NM or M-"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(4, 3).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Vinyl"" && condition === ""VG+/EX"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(4, 4).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Vinyl"" && condition === ""VG"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(4, 5).getValue();
    } else if (material === ""Vinyl"" && condition === ""G/G+"" || ""G+"" || ""G"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(4, 6).getValue(); 
    } else if (material === ""Vinyl"" && condition === ""P"" || ""F"" || ""F/P"") {
      description += var condition_chartSheet.getRange(4, 7).getValue(); 
    } else {
      description += ""No description available."";
    }
  } else {
    description += ""No description available."";
  }
  return description;
}"
```

Please forgive for which I am fairly new to programming. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the current issue in your script and your expected result. Can I ask you about the detail of them? And, in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: Just to clarify... are you trying to populate the "Description" column on "input sheet"?

Comment: Related question: [Two dimensional lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134770/1330560).

Comment: @Tedinoz Yes, I am trying to populate the Description column. In to create a complete description, I know I could parse the values from the notes and title columns, use VLOOkUP and conditional logic when finding the information from the table, and then parse the information again in a separate column. Instead of creating additional, separate columns when parsing, I was wondering if I could just program a script to create a description from the desired columns.

Comment: Do you want/need a script? I did it using @player0 's formula.

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions:

- by formula
- by script

One of the changes made in this answer was to assume that the "Materials" and "Conditions" values on the "Input Sheet" were defined by Data Validation based on data on the Conditions sheet. This ensures consistency between the sources. This is particularly important to eliminate problems with typos, and because the OP's data contains a specific inconsistency:

- Input sheet refers to `VG+/EX`
- Conditions sheet refers `EX, VG+`

Data Validation for "Materials" references Conditions sheet: A2:A10.

Data Validation for "Condition" references Conditions sheet: B2:G2.

---

**FORMULA**

Insert this formula in Cell E2:

`=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C&"×"&D2:D, SPLIT(FLATTEN( IF(Conditions!B2:G="",,Conditions!A2:A&"×"&Conditions!B1:G1&"♦"&Conditions!B2:G)), "♦"), 2, 0)))`

h/t: @player0 [Two dimensional lookup?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70134770/1330560)

---

**SCRIPT**

```
function getDescription() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var dataSheetName = "Sheet2"
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName(dataSheetName)
  var conditionsSheetName = "Conditions"
  var conditionsSheet = ss.getSheetByName(conditionsSheetName)

  var data = dataSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var dataLR = dataSheet.getLastRow()
  var dataMaterials = data.map(function(e){return e[2]})
  var dataCondition = data.map(function(e){return e[3]})

  var conditions = conditionsSheet.getDataRange().getValues()
  var condMaterials = conditions.map(function(e){return e[0]})
  var condConditions = conditions[0]

  var colArray = []

  for (var i=1;i<dataLR;i++){ // skip the header row
    var matResult = condMaterials.indexOf(dataMaterials[i]) // zero-based result
    var condResult = condConditions.indexOf(dataCondition[i]) // zero-based result
    var desc = conditions[matResult][condResult]
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: i: "+i+", Title: "+data[i][0]+", Notes: "+data[i][1]+", Material: "+dataMaterials[i]+", Condition: "+dataCondition[i]+", Description: "+desc)
    var rowArray=[]
    rowArray.push(desc)
    colArray.push(rowArray)
  }
  
  // Logger.log(colArray) // DEBUG
  dataSheet.getRange(2,5,dataLR-1,1).setValues(colArray)
}
```

---

**Sheet: Sheet1**

[image: sheet1]

---

**Sheet: Conditions**

[image: Conditions]